# How to count number of included/excluded white circles in an overlaid binary image?

Tags: python, opencv

I was wondering if there is an available method or existing function that can do this proposed problem.

I create two binary image maps showing different criteria from the same parent image.

For one criteria, I created a binary image that contains coordinates represented by white circles.  As shown below:

[image: small white circles binary image]

For the other criteria, I have another binary image that shows a blob or region of interest also highlighted in white. However, the region isn’t always unanimously white, where there may be tiny dark spots/areas in this region or even multiple regions of blobs.

[image: contour/blobs binary image]

Both binary maps are from the same image and can be overlaid one another.

I basically want to know how to count the number of circles from the first binary image, that were included or excluded in the white regions from the second binary image.

I’m not really sure how to solve this problem and was wondering if anyone has any robust solutions?

I was considering perhaps counting the number of circles/blobs/single blocks of white pixels of a certain size in both binary images. And then from the overlaid image, counting the number of obvious circles (of a certain size) outside of the significant blobs and labelling them as “excluded”, however this may not be robust if regions from the second binary image are the same size (or smaller) than the circles in the  first binary image.

Comment: Can a particular (little) circle lie partly inside and partly outside of a white region?   If so, how do you want to treat it?   Also, the process that generates the circles, could it generate single points instead?  Or, can the circles overlap, in which case, how are they counted?

Comment: Hi, so if a little circle does partly lie in the larger blobbed region, I will assume that it is inside that blobbed region (although this would be highly unlikely to happen). I can actually make the circles even smaller, like 1 pixel points. From what I have seen so far, the circles shouldn't really overlap (especially if they end up being made up of a few pixels). These particular images have dimension sizes of 1664 × 944 pixels.

Comment: I'd suggest making the little circles single points; then, assuming that you implement the images as Numpy arrays, then you can say "np.count_nonzero( m & b )" where "m" is the marker array, "b" is the blob arrray.